# Trigger to Update Opportunity Division Based on User Division

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to update a pick list field Division on Opportunity based on the User or Opportunity Owner Division. So if Sales Rep A User Division is UK, on opportunity creation, I want the Division field on the Opportunity to auto populate to Sales Rep A Division which is UK. I tried to write a Simple trigger but its not working, can some help? My code is below.......

```
trigger UpdateOpportunityDivisonBaseOnUserDivision on Opportunity (before    insert, before update) {
for(Opportunity op : Trigger.new)
{
    User user = new User();
    if ( User.Division !=null )
    {
        op.Division__c = user.Division;
    }
    update op;
}
}
```

Comment: You created an empty User object, you need to get the OwnerID off of the Oppty, and use the UserInfo Class, also move the update out of the for loop

Comment: Maybe do this in process builder or a workflow ? Also you have the Update DML call in the for loop, you will hit limits

Comment: @MihaiNeagoe, how do I do this in Process builder? I have never used this before.

Comment: Big subject, start from here : https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_overview.htm . It's essentially like a simple trigger, without the need to code.

Answer (score 1):

here's some code logic that you will want to use (didn't try to compile this so may need some tweaks):

```
set<Id> userIds = new set<Id>();
for(Opportunity op : Trigger.new){
 userIds.add(op.OwnerId);
}
map<Id,User>  divMap = new map<Id,User>([Select id, division from User where Id In :userIds]);

for(Opportunity op : Trigger.new){
  op.division__c = divMap.get(op.OwnerId).division;
}
```

Since you're using a before trigger you don't need to do the "Update ops" line you originally had.  You just need to set the field.

Comment: Jason -- lines 4-8 can be replaced with one statement using map of `<id,User>` instantiation from SOQL - see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_map_sobject.htm; then change penultimate line to be `op.division__c = divMap.get(op.OwnerId).division;`

Comment: @cropredy - thanks, missed that.  I edited my post for efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone that tried to answer this. This is what finally worked for me should someone wants to do this in the future.

```
trigger UpdateOpportunityDivisonBaseOnUserDivision on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
  User u = [select id, Division from User where Id = : UserInfo.getUserId()];
  for(Opportunity op : Trigger.new){
    if ( u.Division != null ){
        op.Division__c = u.Division;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How you will  get `UserInfo`?